# Worried about Background Verification

Tags: india, background-check

I have resigned from my current job serving notice period.

I recently got a job offer from a big IT company. They have initiated BGV and have given me a conditional offer on it.

There are a few discrepancies in my resume:

1. My post graduation diploma percentage is 73% I had mentioned 66% (Could not collect my diploma due to covid, i had a temporary record of marks which gave me the 66%). I collected the diploma when i cleared the interview and have share the same with the bgv.
2. I could not find a relevant job between my engineering and post graduation. I worked at a contact center to make ends meet(~1year6months). I have provided this info to the BGV. But not mentioned this in my resume.

I am disappointed with myself about these mistakes but i can't do anything now. i am anxious because i found a job after 3 years and now because i made a mistake i don't want to be unemployed.

Comment: _"I am disappointed with myself"_ You shouldn't - life is full of surprises and working in a call center to make ends meet shows that you are responsible individual..

Comment: It doesn’t matter what is on your resume if you filled out the form for the background check accurately. I have multiple versions of my resume tailored for different opportunities that omit various bits of information. Any document where it matters will make you sign to assert that the information in it is true.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of these things should be a significant issue, because it's clear that you're not trying to lie to make yourself look better.

If you'd claimed to have a higher score than you actually did, or you claimed to have experience that you didn't have, those would both be red flags.

Answer (score 1):

What have you mentioned in your resume about the gap between your engineering graduation and post graduation period?

I see that you have not mentioned about the contact center. Then, what have you mentioned? Is it a gap or any other job?

If it is merely a gap and if someone asks about it, then mention that it was in a different field other than IT. Don't bother to mention any other details. Be strict about that.

If anyone asks you about the percentage difference in resume and certificate, you can mention whatever you did you pay here. No other unnecessary thoughts about this.

Also, don't worry about the BGV. You have not given any misleading information.

And keep your job hunt going on. You are already serving your notice period; so, there are high chances that you can get another offer.

Comment: I did speak to my recruiter and mentioned these concerns she said if i have not provided any fake information and certificates i should be fine,but these discrepancies will be notified by the BGV to the hiring manager and it will be his call. Yes out of fear, i have scheduled a few interviews next week. Thanks